# Kubuntu lag and poor user experience

Tags: kubuntu, intel-graphics, framerate

I am having some high CPU usage since yesterday. The Kubuntu I installed is kind of lagging and has some fps drops I might say. I even tried htop to see which process is consuming CPU. The experience overall is not smooth at all. Can someone help?

Comment: And which process was using so much CPU?

Comment: I face GUI lag all the time when I boot up. After some time it gets better and again lags

Comment: Kubuntu does not ship with a magic 'run lousy' feature that you simply need to disable. Kubuntu runs well for most users. You must provide much more technical detail of you wish to get useful help here. If you did not understand Dark Sinus' question, or did not understand how to answer it, please explain the parts you need help with so we can help you.

Comment: Did a fresh install of KDE neon . Everything works fine